# PyAudio не устанавливается

Tags: python, pip

Не устанавливается библиотека PyAudio. Пробовал pip install PyAudio. Сначала сказал скачать Microsoft visual c++. Скачал и установил. Теперь эта ошибка

```
C:\Users\sulay\Downloads\Python\Artificial inteligence>pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyAudio ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\sulay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\sulay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xwgazswg\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\sulay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-m8k2zafm --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\sulay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\sulay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for PyAudio
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\sulay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\sulay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xwgazswg\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\sulay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k_mb8hmx\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\sulay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include -Ic:\users\sulay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\sulay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\sulay\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xwgazswg\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\sulay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k_mb8hmx\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\sulay\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xwgazswg\PyAudio\
```

Comment: Та же сложность, решения пока еще не нашел(

Answer (score 5):

Обошел это при помощи скачивания и установки неоф. пакета pyaudio с расширением .whl:

1. Скачал пакет с расширением .whl по ссылке
   https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio Необходимо
   выбрать версию pyaudio, которая соответствует версии python,
   например, если у вас установлен python3.7.x (x64 версия), то
   выбираем пакет PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl, где cp37
   указывает на версию python3.7.x, а amd64 на соответствующую
   разрядность.
2. После загрузки установил пакет при помощи pip (переходим в папку с пакетом и устанавливаем его, указав полное название пакета с его расширением):

   ```
   cd <папка с пакетом pyaudio.whl>
   pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
   ```

В итоге я получил сообщение `Successfully installed PyAudio-0.2.11`, т.е. пакет pyaudio был успешно установлен.

Comment: Я попытался установить пакет, но у меня вывелось ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. Что мне делать?

Comment: @illarion вы уверены, что на вашем компьютере установлена Windows x64 и Python x64?

Answer (score 5):

Есть еще один вариант для установки - это pipwin:

```
pip install pipwin 
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Если это делается для оффлайн распознавания речи при установке Pocket Sphinx, то далее:

```
pipwin install pocketsphinx
```

Надеюсь, что это было кому-нибудь полезно..

Comment: братан, спасибо
Помог