# Как запустить библиотеку PyAudio в Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyaudio

подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить библиотеку PyAudio в Jupyter Notebook. Скачал её, но использовать могу только через IDLE.

Comment: IDE? Установите через `pip` и она будет доступна в юпитере.

Comment: через pip в юпитере бесконечная загрузка(звёздочка)

Comment: На чем юпитер установлен - windows или GNU/Linux?

Comment: установлен на windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-windows-how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PyAudio не устанавливается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927657/pyaudio-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f)